# Zip file size limit for package deployment in Developer Workbench?

Tags: workbench

Does anyone know what is the zip file size limit for package deployment in Developer Workbench?  From the github, it seems like it should be 40 MB
https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/pull/793/commits/f5886360874ee30768736ce89a5e0e0d8b0e57dc

However, I have 4.4 MB zip file (with ContentAsset binary files) that DW will not accept.  I upload the file but get a message "No file uploaded for deployment".

I've tried removing some of the asset files to get the zip file size down to about 1.8 MB and that does load.